# Evaluate math expression in c# that should handle whitespace if it exists

Tags: math

I am trying to use the following code to evaluate math expression. currently, the expression parser only works if there is a whitespace between every character. ex: (x + y) *2.... if the expression is (x+y)*2, the expression does not evaluate. Trying to use regex so the expression evaluates with or without spaces,but still unable to meet the goal. Any direction/help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "(x + y)*2";
      string pattern = "\\s+";
      string replacement = " ";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the Replacement String to be in the above output?

Comment: Are you fine with extra spaces in the output like: `( x   +   y ) * 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If extra spaces between the terms is fine, please try this code:

```
public static void Main()
{
  string input = "(x + y)*2";
  string pattern = "";
  string replacement = " ";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
}
```

Comment: Thanks shruti. Tried the above code, it's inserting spaces between each character in the expression ex: ( x + y ) * 2, which is fine, because I am now able to evaluate the expression with or without spaces.

Comment: How can I modify the code to avoid inserting the extra space if the input already contains a space. for ex: if I enter ( x + y ) * 2, by using the above code I get the output as (  x  +  y  )  *  2.  Is it possible to insert the space only when the input has no spaces and in other cases, trim the existing one extra white space. please let me know.

Comment: @Manisha Adding another answer, not a good way to do it, but will get you right result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
  string input = "(x + y)*2";
  string pattern = "";
  string replacement = " ";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

  pattern = "  ";
  replacement = " ";
  rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);
  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
 }
```